# how to set .vim color scheme to vim editor OS X

Tags: macos, vim, colors, syntax-highlighting, iterm2

I downloaded some .vim color scheme files in github and moved them by

```
sudo mv ~.vim /usr/share/vim/vim73/colors
```

then I wrote

```
colorscheme ~.vim
```

in vimrc. The original schemes already existed, are adjusted very well, however, my downloaded ~.vim files are not adjusted. just black and white. Why this happened and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your colorsscheme in your local vim settings =>

Usually => ~/.vim/colors

For instance :

```
sudo mv Monokai.vim ~/.vim/colors
```

And add to your ~/.vimrc

```
colorscheme Monokai
```

(without the .vim extension)

Comment: I solved it, but thanks anyway I confused that there's no colors folder in .vim

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solved it.
The vim73 folder has runtime files so it is never recommended to edit them.

What I confused is there's no colors folder in ~/.vim .

However, when I make the colors folder by mkdir colors, and move the ~.vim files in here, it is solved perfectly.